# Checking if there is any Document matching a certain condition in Mongoose (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So basically I want to run through the documents and with the .find method check if there is a Document that meets the condition, like this:

```
//example model

const example = new ExampleModel ({
  exampleName : "randomName",
  exampleValue : 0
})

const doc = ExampleModel.findOne( {name : "randomName"} )

if (doc) console.log("There is a Document with that name!")
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't work and when I do `console.log(doc)` it logs a Query but I want the document and not a Query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try doing `((await ExampleModel.findOne({name: "randomName" }).exec()) !== null)`

Comment: You need chaning then and catch try like this ```doc.then(result => console.log(result)).catch(error => console.log(error))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.findOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) returns [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html), which has to be executed, and then the results will come asynchronously.

Basically, you have to call [`.exec()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-exec) and then await the returned promise:

```js
const example = new ExampleModel({
  exampleName : "randomName",
  exampleValue : 0,
})

ExampleModel
  .findOne({ name : "randomName" })
  .exec()
  .then((doc) => {
    if (doc) console.log("There is a Document with that name!")
  })
```

… or (using `async` / `await` syntax):

```js
async function main() {
  const example = new ExampleModel({
    exampleName : "randomName",
    exampleValue : 0,
  })

  const doc = await ExampleModel.findOne({ name : "randomName" }).exec()

  if (doc) console.log("There is a Document with that name!")
}

main()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me! There's only one issue, the .then method logs "Promise { <pending> }".

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't. Are you sure, your code is the same?

Comment: You don't need the result of `.then()`, you rather have to provide the callback to it as an argument, - see [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Yes, exactly the same, except for the variable names and stuff but its core its the same. If I put an await behind the ExampleModel it gives an error, something like await is only for async functions or something like that.

Comment: Yes, `await` can only be used in `async` context, i.e. directly inside `async function` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function))

Comment: Oh yeah I was returning to get a result so that's why it was showing the Promise Pending stuff. Now it works, but what if I want to return a value? Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't. Once async, always async.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for answering me! Have a good day!

Answer (score -2):

```
//example model

const example = new ExampleModel ({
  exampleName : "randomName",
  exampleValue : 0
})

ExampleModel.findOne( {name : "randomName"} )
.then (doc => {
if (doc) console.log("There is a Document with that name!")
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Try this out!